# get substring from C string in C++

Tags: c++, string, substring

I have C string

```
   char s[] = "n1=1&n2=2&name=test&sername=test2";
```

I need to take from the string value name, ie, "test" and written in a separate variable.

So I need to find the value between "&name=" and the next &

Comment: You could build an `std::string` and use [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

Comment: So you'd use `strlen()` to find an end iterator, `std::search()` to find the position of the where the parameter starts, and `std::find()` where it ends. What part exactly is your problem?

Comment: You can use the pointer as an array.

Comment: FWIW, `s` should be `const` here.

Comment: As a generic solution, you could first split on `&` to get the collection of `pairs` (a=b), then split on `=` to get a key and value for each pair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you tagged this as C++ I'll use `std::string` instead:

```
char s[] = "n1=1&n2=2&name=test&sername=test2";
string str(s);
string slice = str.substr(str.find("name=") + 5);

string name = slice.substr(0, slice.find("&"));
```

You could also do this with regex and capture all those values at once, also saving the time of creating a string.

```
char s[] = "n1=1&n2=2&name=test&sername=test2";

std::regex e ("n1=(.*)&n2=(.*)&name=(.*)&sername=(.*)");
std::cmatch cm;
std::regex_match(s,cm,e);

cout << cm[3] << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks.It is that I need.